# Incorrectly Formatted Numbers in XML File - How to Change ? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, parsing, format

I have an xml file which has many numbers which are formatted incorrectly in scientific format - e.g 0.000004 is formatted as 4e-006.

Can anyone suggest a good way to change the format of these numbers ? I am parsing the file into xCode, however would prefer to change the xml if possible.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no need to change the XML itself, just use `NSDecimalNumber`: `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4e-006"]`

Comment: Thanks Tilo. Would this work given that some of the numbers are decimal and some are not ?

Comment: Sure. You can easily try it yourself, e.g. by doing this: `NSLog(@"Number: %@",[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"123"]);`